# GKE automatically restarted cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

Auto-Scaling is OFF and Cluster-Upgrade is OFF but still dont know why cluster get restarted today morning. All Nodes got replace/change and All Pods got restarted

Reason is that it got restarted due to node got upgrade from 1.22 to 1.23 version

I have Regular Version in GKE Cluster

Answer (score 3):

You should double-check with Google support (if you have a support plan), but I know from painful experience that if you're running a version of GKE that falls out of support, they may force-upgrade you to keep you within support, even if you have cluster upgrade turned off -- unless you use a maintenance exclusion.

The REGULAR channel release notes are here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes-regular

The December 5th one is probably the one that affected you.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable node auto-upgrade, you are responsible for ensuring that the cluster's nodes run a version compatible with the cluster's version, and that the version adheres to the [Kubernetes version and version skew support policy](https://kubernetes.io/releases/version-skew-policy/).

Nodes running versions that have reached their [end of life](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/versioning#lifecycle) date are auto-upgraded even when auto-upgrade is disabled, to ensure supportability and version skew compatibility.

For more information you can read this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades#disable).

You can also check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades#mitgation) for temporary mitigation.